# Magnitude of relative velocity between two frames in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, relative-motion, equivalence-principle

It seems to be taken trivially, and it is indeed intuitive, that the relative velocity $v$ of some frame $O$ with respect to $O'$ is the same **in magnitude** to the relative velocity of $O'$ with respect to $O$. Is there any way to prove this? I've seen some tricks with rotating the relative motion axis by 180 degrees, but i'm not sure I get that.

Comment: Anything will help, thank you. I would just like to see how it is  possible to get to this conclusion without pure intuition.

Comment: You got the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a symmetry argument.

There is no absolute difference between $O$ and $O'$.

But if the speed of  $O$ as seen from $O'$ is not the same as the speed of $O'$ seen from $O$, $|v'| \ne |v|$, then it must be larger or smaller: $|v'|>|v|$ or
$|v|>|v'|$.   That would give an absolute difference between the two frames, so it can't happen and the speeds, $|v|$ and $|v'|$, must be the same.

When you extend this to consider velocities the minus sign is allowable as that's just about the choice of direction of the $x$ axis

Comment: This question and this answer deeply trouble me. I am not able to convince myself that it is true, apart from using my "intuition". When you say that there is an absolute difference between the two frames, *with respect to whom*? Would such a difference lead to a contradiction? If so, what is it?